Installing xtensor package for building Navigation2 from Source for ROS2-Humble, on Ubuntu Focal (20.04)
I'm very new to ROS and Linux in general, so I apologize in advance for any clear misunderstandings I have that lead to this problem.
I'm attempting to build the ROS2 package Navigation2 from source, for use with ROS2 Humble, on Ubuntu Focal (20.04). Both my ROS installation, and other packages, have been built from source, so I'm confident that my process is sound, but I'll include it regardless. Clone the repository into the source folder, checkout the correct branch for my version, and then attempt to build.
When building Navigation2 and it's various packages, I run into an error on the package nav2_mppi_controller, specifically that there is a lack of configuration files provided by the xtensor package. I'll include the full error below for posterity.
--- stderr: nav2_mppi_controller
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findxtensor.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor" with any
  of the following names:

    xtensorConfig.cmake
    xtensor-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "xtensor" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "xtensor_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "xtensor" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


---


In light of this, I went on a search to figure out what the xtensor package was, why I didn't have it, and where I can get it. After finding this, I was distraught to find that there doesn't seem to be a version of xtensor that supports 20.04.
Also important to note, I did try using Rosdep to install the necessary dependencies, and it doesn't seem to be able to find what it's looking for, thus my attempts to install manually.
If anyone can point me in the direction of how to get a version of this package that works with 20.04, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

I actually had the same issue recently, but I am on 22.04 :P Why don't you also try to build xtensor from source?

You will need to install xtensor on 20.04 from source, it is not available in apt and one of many reasons MPPI isn't available in any ROS distributions supporting 20.04.

Thanks- built xtensor and xtl from source, and I'm off to the races. I ended up just ignoring the MPPI package- good motivation to push for an upgrade to 22.04.
